# tsc throws `TS2307: Cannot find module` for a local file

Tags: typescript

I've got a simple example project using TypeScript: https://github.com/unindented/ts-webpack-example

Running `tsc -p .` (with `tsc` version 1.8.10) throws the following:

```
app/index.ts(1,21): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'components/counter'.
components/button/index.ts(2,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'shared/backbone_base_view'.
components/button/index.ts(3,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'shared/backbone_with_default_render'.
components/counter/index.ts(2,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'shared/backbone_base_view'.
components/counter/index.ts(3,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'shared/backbone_with_default_render'.
components/counter/index.ts(4,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'shared/backbone_with_subviews'.
components/counter/index.ts(5,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'components/button'.
```

It complains about all imports of local files, like the following:

```
import Counter from 'components/counter';
```

If I change it to a relative path it works, but I don't want to, as it makes my life more difficult when moving files around:

```
import Counter from '../components/counter';
```

The `vscode` codebase does not use relative paths, but everything works fine for them, so I must be missing something in my project: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/0e81224179fbb8f6fda18ca7362d8500a263cfef/src/vs/languages/typescript/common/typescript.ts#L7-L14

You can check out my GitHub repo, but in case it helps here's the `tsconfig.json` file I'm using:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "dist",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Funny thing is, building the project through `webpack` using `ts-loader` works fine, so I'm guessing it's just a configuration issue...

Answer (score 173, accepted):

@vladima replied to [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8920#issuecomment-223052268):

> The way the compiler resolves modules is controlled by
> moduleResolution option that can be either `node` or `classic` (more
> details and differences can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Module%20Resolution.md)). If this setting is omitted
> the compiler treats this setting to be `node` if module is `commonjs` and
> `classic` - otherwise. In your case if you want `classic` module
> resolution strategy to be used with `commonjs` modules - you need to set
> it explicitly by using
>
> ```
> {
>     "compilerOptions": {
>         "moduleResolution": "node"
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: I am seeing this error: `error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'moduleResolution'.`

Comment: Required if you are using `import * as microsoftTeams from "@microsoft/teams-js";` in an static .html which uses `.js` files compiled with `tsc` for MS teams.

Comment: I get this error even with moduleResolution = node

Comment: Visual Studio threw this error because it refused to resolve the include path of a local package. Three hours later, comparing module versions we found that VS did not like some quiet "implicit any" errors within the package. The local builds of the package didn't complain, but VS really did not want to use it.

Comment: I didn't understand: if I want `classic` I've to set `node`?

Comment: this answer needs updated. `node` now refers to older versions of NodeJS (below 16 IIRC). for non-ancient versions `node16` or `nodenext` should be used. these are currently equivalent but that will probably change in the not too distant future.

Answer (score 43):

In some cases you just need to update the `include` array.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "tests/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", ".vscode"]
}
```

Comment: Check also your `exclude` property! My problem was that `exclude` was excluding some of my files (of course, this was a mistake).

Comment: This was the solution for me. I moved `"exclude": [..., "**/*.test.ts"]` to my `tsconfig.build.json` file so that typescript can resolve modules during development, but still exclude test files on build.

Comment: `"baseUrl": "."` worked for me

Answer (score 21):

My problem was building in different environments. In my OSX build there wasn't any problem. But when i try to build on Linux environment, it was failing. The reason behind that was case sensitivity of operating systems. Anyone who suffers from this problem please also check case sensitivity in your imports.

File structure was:

```
/X/Y.ts
```

My import was:

```
import Y from "./x/Y.ts";
```

So, my fix was just making "x" uppercase.

```
import Y from "./X/Y.ts";
```

Comment: This is what the `tsconfig.json` option `forceConsistentCasingInFileNames` protects you from. By setting this option to `true` tsc will give you an error if you import with a different case than what the file actually has, so you can find these problems earlier even if you are on a case-insensitive filesystem.

Comment: MY mistake was to omit `.ts` in the import doc and it started working again after adding it.

Comment: Same issue but we had `Index.ts` with a capital "I"

Comment: Somehow I had both `xx/y.ts` and `xX/z.ts` on the same commit, but only `xX` on the filesystem (OSX). I was able to build locally but the build system that ran on Linux yielded TS2307. I simply rebased amending the commit (unstaged the `xx/y.ts` and staged `xX/y.ts`).

Comment: this solved my issue, thanks, I cannot believe it, in TS, this different case will give us this issue.

in my case, the issue is only in remote docker pipeline, but it is fully fine locally

Answer (score 8):

In VS2019, the **project** property page, *TypeScript Build* tab has a setting (dropdown) for "Module System".  When I changed that from "ES2015" to **CommonJS**, then VS2019 IDE stopped complaining that it could find neither  axios nor redux-thunk (TS2307).

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom",
      "es2015.promise"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts",
    "node_modules",
    "obj",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src",
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "@types/**/*.d.ts",
    "node_modules/axios",
    "node_modules/redux-thunk"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can't find this configuration. Where is it?

Comment: It is located in `tsconfig.json` file.

Answer (score 5):

> The vscode codebase does not use relative paths, but everything works fine for them

Really depends on your module loader. If you are using `systemjs` with `baseurl` then it would work. VSCode uses its own custom module loader (based on an old version of requirejs).

## Recommendation

Use relative paths as that is what `commonjs` supports. If you move files around you will get a typescript compile time error (a good thing) so you will be better off than a great majority of pure js projects out there (on npm).

Comment: Loading the `vscode` codebase in Visual Studio Code itself, I get no squiggly lines, so Visual Studio Code somehow understands things like `import {notImplemented} from 'vs/base/common/errors';`, regardless of where the file that contains that code lives. How do they do it?

Answer (score 5):

I got this error, too. But with a very strange VSCode and GitHub behaviour. I renamed my files from `page.ts` to `Page.ts` and pushed the changes to the remote branch. Everything went well on my local system. But my build fails on GitHub Actions with the message, that the module `Page` was not found.

After some time, I recognized that the files some how were not renamed on the remote branch (but any further changes were present). I renamed them via GitHub web UI again and my build runs successful.

So checks this on the remote branch if your CI/CD build fails with TS2307.

Answer (score 4):

Adding `"baseUrl": "."` will allow absolute paths (e.g. `"src/components/button"`).

And, adding `"paths"` will allow starting from a specific folder.
So, in your `tsconfig.json` file, you could add:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/components/*": ["src/components/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Also, after adding that configuration, you might need to restart VS Code to have it working properly.

Comment: Just reading through the paths code. I've not seen this key value pattern before with an @ sign etc... Is this language for the key important, does it do anything or signal anything to tsc?

Comment: @Lauro235 no it doesn't mean anything special, it's purpose is just to namespace the imports

Answer (score 2):

If you want only disappear with the error code and the red underline, you can put the following line before your imports (but this is NOT recommended):

```
/*eslint import/no-unresolved:*/
```

To this line work you can add to your tsconfig file the following:

```
"include": ["src", "src/**/*.ts", "tests/**/*.ts"]
```

This worked to me, but this is not the best way to solve the problem, it simply eases my anguish.

Answer (score 1):

If use webstorm, press Ctrl+Alt+S and bring up the settings window. Languages&Frameworks>TypeScript, enable "use tsconfig.json" option.

Comment: In WebStorm 2020.1 this option has been reworded to say, "Also for projects without tsconfig.json."

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the error is thrown when your class files are not properly named, e.g. I had class files named `Employee` instead of `Employee.ts`

You need to rename all your typescript files to end with either `.ts` or `.d.ts`

Answer (score 1):

I faced the issue and the fix was to provide correct `baseUrl` and `paths` in `compilerOptions` in *tsconfig.json* file :-

```
{
...
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "moduleResolution": "node",
   ...
    "baseUrl": ".", // Here... try with correct values and the issue should get fixed
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/*"] // Here... try with correct values and the issue should get fixed
    }
  }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error on updates from `npm run watch` and `npm run hot`. There were no errors the first time, or when triggering `npm run dev` or `npm run prod`.

In the end, this was a combination of `webpack` and `ts-loader`, see:

- [npm run watch/hot only successful on the first run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69120779/npm-run-watch-hot-only-successful-on-the-first-run/69132469#69132469)

Answer (score 0):

i have the similar problem, and i'm using webstorm. i modified `include` option in `tsconfig.js` file as shown below:

```json
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.tsx"
  ]
```

and viola, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding, "baseUrl": ".", worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

include  the following line after compilerOptions{} in your tsconfig.json.

```
"exclude": ["node_modules"].
```

this solved the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --save @types/react
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. However, adding this option to `tsconnfig.json` did:

```
"importHelpers": true, /* Allow importing helper functions from tslib once per project, instead of including them per-file. */
```

which in turn will add the extension `.js` to the imported module name.

Answer (score -1):

Disclaimer: Not (!) what OP asked for but probably useful to other visitors of this question:

**Change your path to a relative one.**

From

```
import x from 'src/foobar/x';
```

to

```
import x from '../foobar/x';
```

Answer (score -1):

removing captalize letter in the beggining of the file name worked for me, I am working on a windows machine and it worked good on local the problem was when I tryed to deploy to a linux machine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

In the Webstorm, you can create a new file instead of what you have now,
copy the content from the old file to the new one,
remove the old file,
and then rename the new file to the old file.
now you can do the import file
this is work for me.

Comment: Please use your answer as a comment