# error TS2307: Cannot find module (external, private module)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have read similiar questions including [tsc throws `TS2307: Cannot find module` for a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548734/tsc-throws-ts2307-cannot-find-module-for-a-local-file) .

I have a privat external module (on a local git server) and I try to include that into my application - this works.

- phpStorm can resolve the classes perfectly!
- the app **throws the error TS2307 but runs perfectly**!

I wonder why the transpiler throws this error although everything looks fine and I need this error to be gone for a stable deployment.

The module tsconfig.json looks like:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "ES6",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "sourceMap": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "declaration": true,
        "noResolve": false
    },
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

I tried several combinations of the above without success.

I have a `Main.ts` in the module like

```
export {default as Logger}  from "./Logger";
export {ILogger as ILogger} from './ILogger';
```

Where the class and the interface are

```
export interface ILogger { }
export default class Logger implements ILogger { }
```

And in the app I use:

```
import {Logger, ILogger} from "logging";
```

The error happens when I try to transpile the app, not the module. Again, everything works when running the app through node and when coding in phpStorm but on transpiling I get:

```
src/Main.ts(9,39): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'logging'.
```

**Update:**

Looks like a bug in `tsc`: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14332

Answer (score 0):

In our project error was resolved by including typescript files and definitions in include key as follows

```
  "include": ["global.d.ts", "./app/**/*.tsx", "./app/**/*.ts"],
```

app contains typescript files and global.d.ts contains declarations for local packages as follows

```
declare module 'uicomponents-react-native';
declare module '@styles';
declare module '@styles/*';

declare module '@common';

declare module '@constants';
declare module '@constants/*';

declare module '@utils/*';
declare module '@utils';

declare module '@helper/*';
declare module '@helper';
```

Answer (score -1):

We just had to set

```
"noResolve": false
```

to `true` and it finally did work.