# tsc throws error TS2307: Cannot find module for a local installed module

Tags: typescript, local, yarnpkg, tsc

I've read these similar questions:

- [tsc throws `TS2307: Cannot find module` for a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548734/tsc-throws-ts2307-cannot-find-module-for-a-local-file) - my problem is different because I'm *installing* a local package, not just referencing a local file.
- [error TS2307: Cannot find module (external, private module)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42481149/error-ts2307-cannot-find-module-external-private-module) - my problem might be similar to this one (there's not enough detail for me to tell for sure).  But turning on `noResolve` causes other problems (and seems like a hack since I'm seeing a difference in behavior between macOS/Linux/Windows)

In my Typescript project, I have two directories:

```
core/
  package.json
  ...
app/
  package.json
  ...
```

Within `app/` I have installed the `core/` module using `yarn` like this:

```
yarn add file:../core
```

which shows up in `app/package.json` as:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "my-core": "file:../core",
    ...
  }
}
```

On macOS and Linux, running `tsc` from within `app/` works fine.  But when I run `tsc` on Windows, I get this:

```
C:\proj\app>cmd /c yarn compile 
yarn compile v0.27.5
$ cross-env NODE_ENV=production tsc
src/thing/appstate.ts(4,29): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'my-core'.
error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

Here's my `app/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "umd",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "listEmittedFiles": false,
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Is this a yarn bug? Or a Typescript bug?  Or am I doing something wrong? :)