# TypeScript compiler won't find node module I installed

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I try to separate Angular 2 module I created and import it back to app using npm, but I keep running into problems with it. Right now I'm stuck with
`error TS2307: Cannot find module 'preloader'` I added

```
"paths": {
  "preloader": ["../node_modules/angular2-resource-preloader/dist/"]
}
```

to my tsconfig and dist folder contains .d.ts files. I also added "types" property to module package.json, but I keep getting error TS2307.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548734/tsc-throws-ts2307-cannot-find-module-for-a-local-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Und3rTow I researched TS documentation more, and found out that with `"moduleResolution": "node"` I have to add path to module, not folder with main files. So correct path in my case is `"../node_modules/angular2-resource-preloader/"`.

Thank you for assistance.