# TS2307: Cannot find module

Tags: typescript

```
import Locator from '@company/locator';

function func(locator: Locator) {

}
```

**error**

```
TS2307: Cannot find module '@company/locator'
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": { "@company/locator": ["node_modules/@company/locator"] }
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "es2017",
      "es2016",
      "es2015",
      "dom",
      "es6",
      "es5"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "strict": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "types",
    "types": [
      "node",
      "jest"
    ]
  }
}
```

`@company/locator` is a node module we wrote in typescript. It contains a class named `Locator`. I am trying to import that class. Typescript compiler looking into the correct path (`node_modules/@company/locator`). but says locator.ts not found. `@company/locator` module has a `types` folder which contains `index.d.ts`. That's where Locator is exported. How to make compiler look into that `@company/locator/types` folder. Can someone help me in fixing this?

`tsc --traceResolution` gives

```
 Module resolution kind is not specified, using 'Classic'.
    'baseUrl' option is set to '/Users/lch/Documents/project', using this value to resolve non-relative module name '@company/locator'.
    'paths' option is specified, looking for a pattern to match module name '@company/locator'.
    Module name '@company/locator', matched pattern '@company/locator'.
    Trying substitution 'node_modules/@company/locator/types', candidate module location: 'node_modules/@company/locator/types'.
    File '/Users/lch/Documents/project/node_modules/@company/locator.ts' does not exist.
    File '/Users/lch/Documents/project/node_modules/@company/locator.tsx' does not exist.
    File '/Users/lch/Documents/project/node_modules/@company/locator.d.ts' does not exist.
    Directory '/Users/lch/Documents/project/src/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
```

Comment: Can you run `tsc --traceResolution` and check the output?

Comment: Did your update answer your question?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Yes

Comment: "moduleResolution": "Node" solved the issue. No idea why?

Comment: There are sections on `classic` vs `node` module resolution in the documentation here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tsc throws \`TS2307: Cannot find module\` for a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548734/tsc-throws-ts2307-cannot-find-module-for-a-local-file)