# How to import { Athlete } from "app/Athlete"?

Tags: angular

I stucked. I am doing example Angular application from one of the books, where are sometimes mistakes in the code. And I can not find solution for one of them.

After running the app, I am getting an error:

> ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts:2:25 - error TS2307: Cannot find
> module 'app/Athlete' or its corresponding type declarations.
>
> 2 import { Athlete } from "app/Athlete";

My code is below. **tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
]
}
```

**app.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Athlete } from "app/Athlete";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<h1>Pięciu najlepszych zawodników w Kona</h1>
  <app-athlete-list (selected)=showDetails($event)>Wczytywanie listy zawodników...</app-athlete-list>
  Wybrałeś: {{selectedAthlete}}`
})
export class AppComponent {
  selectedAthlete: string;

  constructor (){
    this.selectedAthlete="żaden";
  }

  showDetails(selectedAthlete: Athlete) {
    this.selectedAthlete=selectedAthlete.name;
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AthleteService } from './athlete.service';
import { AthleteListComponent } from './athlete-list.component';
import { AthleteComponent } from './athlete.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AthleteListComponent,
    AthleteComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [AthleteService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**athlete.ts**:

```
export class Athlete {
  name: string;
  country: string;
  time: string;
}
```

**NOTE**: Please note, that `athlete.ts` is in the same directory as `app.component.ts`.

I tried already [this fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37568841/12603542), but did not work. And could not find anything else. I will appreciate for your help.

Comment: what happens when you have import { Athlete } from "./Athlete";

Comment: Also I don't know which IDE you are using, but in IntelliJ if you delete the import and then right click on error in code it will auto import the file for you from the correct path.

Comment: @E.Maggini I use Notepad++ currently, and just compile with Angular CLI

Comment: @Sajeetharan dem, it worked! I missed a thing, that in **app.module.ts** all class imports are with `from './`. Thank you!

Comment: It comes with a 30 days trial and personally I think it is well worth the purchase cost. You should check it out. :)

Comment: @E.Maggini thenks, I will consider it. But my target is to use Angular with ASP.NET Core, and TS is well supported in VS 2017, as far as I know. But for learning with books and documentation, maybe I will try **IntelliJ**, if I will get tired with **Notepad++** :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to:

```
import { Athlete } from 'src/app/Athlete';
```

Comment: It works, same like approach of @Sajeetharan : `import { Athlete } from "./Athlete";` Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You are having the wrong path, As i mentioned in the comment change it to,

```
import { Athlete } from "./Athlete";
```