# Why would some Angular modules import while other do not?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem with a module that I cant seem to get to import.

Typescript 2.7 Node 10

pxl-ng-security shows an error in VSCode and VS2019.  If I hover over it, it shows error 2307

Here is the import section of the file.

myfile.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { TokenService } from 'pxl-ng-security';
```

The gulp file is pointing to tsconfig-library.json so I believe the means its using that file instead of the standard tsconfig.json.

tsconfig-library.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "stripInternal": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src-embedded",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "files": [
    "./src-embedded/index.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipTemplateCodeGen": true
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried using ../../node_modules/pxl-ng-security and it has the same problem.  Intellisense sees it and fill it in.  I have confirmed that the folder is indeed in that location.  I have deleted it from node_modules and done a npm-install -project-local and the module comes back, so it would seem the module is healthy and correct.

Running tsc -p . gives the following error

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'pxl-ng-security' or its
> corresponding type declarations.

If I go ahead and try and run gulp the error is"

> Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Could not resolve pxl-ng-security

New Details.
I jumped on a CI/CD server and noticed that this is building fine.  Same code working on it.  I installed vscode on it, just to see if it showed the same ts2307 error.  It was fine.  I checked versions of Node and Typescript and they both match.  The mystery continues

Comment: What is the question/problem?

Comment: I believe that you are not able to import despite installing the module correctly, right? Tried restarting your your ide?

Comment: Sorry about the poor question.  I have edited it.  Also I have restarted my IDE and used multiple IDEs.

Comment: I don't see that package listed on npm.

Comment: Its a private registry

Comment: There are quite a [large number of questions about error TS2307 on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=TS2307+is%3Aq). Have you looked at any of them?

Comment: I have looked at quite a few, and I am still going through them

Comment: Hey joey, I just checked on my local and i found its missing the includes array, add it like my post below, if it works mark as answer please. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `include: array` just add/update the `include array` per where you installed it.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  // you are missing the includes array
  "include": [
     "src/**/*.ts", 
     "tests/**/*.ts",
     // ADD your module here below**** with correct path
     "node_modules/pxl-ng-security"
   ],
  //"exclude": ["node_modules", ".vscode"]
}
```

---

**Update to address your modified question:**

You have to setup how your compiler or your development environment is helping resolve those node modules. Its a tricky, or `more than one way to do it/moduleResolution/ModuleLoader`, because it can be controlled/configured in the tool if the compiler option is not setup (last option), try these below..

> to change in `VS Code`
>
> - Check which module loader are you using, if you are using commonjs, systemjs with baseurl then it would work. you may want to check since VSCode uses its own custom module loader (based on an old version of requirejs).

> to change in `Visual Studio`
>
> - If you want to change VS Studio module system, find the VS2019 project properties, then in the TypeScript Build tab a dropdown setting change the "`Module System`" from "ES2015" to CommonJS,

> Lastly to understand how your compiler module resolution is works look [here if you don't choose to use node](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37568841/6085193)

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my question after you answered.  I believe its using tsconfig-library.json.  I tried adding your section to each of them and tested it with no change.  I made sure the path was correct.  Reading up on includes it seems that refers to TypeScript files, not node_modules, but I am still reading up.  Thanks for the answer, Im still playing with it, to see if it correct

Comment: @joey I think I understand your issue, it _could be in the tool / IDE or the setup_ of the compiler options for module resolution and module loading. Try those I will check back in later next week.