# npm run watch/hot only successful on the first run

Tags: laravel, typescript, vuejs2, laravel-mix, hot-module-replacement

#### Background:

I added TypeScript support to my existing project, so I added `ts-loader` and `typescript`. I think, I configured everything right and it is working fine in `dev` and `prod` mode.

I would like to update gradually, keeping all the JavaScript code in place and using TypeScript for everything new or where there is a need for refactoring. So it may be important to note that `TableValue.vue` is an old js component.

#### Problem:

##### Edit: It also occurs with `npm run watch`

When I run [`npm run hot`](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/hot-module-replacement) in `package.json`: `"scripts": { ..., "hot": "mix watch --hot", ...}` it only works on the first try. As soon as I change any file and trigger a recompile, I get:

```
√ Mix: Compiled successfully in 19.15s
webpack compiled successfully

// Here the recompile is triggered
i Compiling Mix
√ Mix: Compiled with some errors in 509.01ms
ERROR in C:\fakepath\resources\js\components\test\component.vue.ts
24:23-41
[tsl] ERROR in C:\fakepath\resources\js\components\test\component.vue.ts(24,24)
      TS2307: Cannot find module './TableValue.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

I suspect that this error comes from `ts-loader`, but why is everything working on the first try?

I could just ignore this error, but then [hot module replacement](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/hot-module-replacement) is unusable, because I have to manually trigger a new build process every time anyway.

- Has someone got such an setup working?
- What can I do to solve this error?

---

#### Infos:

I'm working with:

- Laravel 8.58
- Laravel Mix 6.0.25
- Vue 2.6.14
- ts-loader 9.2.5
- typescript 4.4.2

Here the script tag from the test component:

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue, { PropType } from 'vue';

import TableValue from "./TableValue.vue";
import Model from "@/js/types/model.js";

export default Vue.extend({
  name: "TestComponent",
  components: {
    TableValue
  },
  props: {
    'model': {
      type: Object as PropType<Model>,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
});
</script>
```

Project Structure:

```
app/
bootstrap/
config/
database/
node_modules/
public/
resources/
  js/
    components/
    store/
    types/
    views/
    app.js
    bootstrap.js
    routes.js
    shims-vue.d.ts
  lang/
  sass/
  views/
routes/
storage/
tests/
vendor/
composer.json
composer.lock
tsconfig.json
package-lock.json
package.json
phpunit.xml
vs.code-workspace
webpack.mix.js
```

`webpack.mix.js`:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const ResolveTypeScriptPlugin = require("resolve-typescript-plugin").default;

mix.webpackConfig({
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: "ts-loader",
                options: { appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/] },
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.vue'],
        alias: {
            '@': __dirname + '/resources'
        },
        fullySpecified: false,
        plugins: [new ResolveTypeScriptPlugin()]
    },
    devtool: 'source-map'
}).sourceMaps();

mix.ts('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.sass', 'public/css').sourceMaps()
    .vue();

mix.extract();
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "esnext",
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": [
                "resources/*"
            ]
        },
        "lib": [
            "esnext",
            "dom",
            "dom.iterable",
            "scripthost"
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "resources/js/shims-vue.d.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
        "resources/js/**/*.ts",
        "resources/js/**/*.vue",
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        ".vscode",
        "app",
        "bootstrap",
        "config",
        "database",
        "public",
        "routes",
        "storage",
        "tests",
        "vendor"
    ]
}
```

#### Update:

When I remove `shims-vue.d.ts`, I get the error immediately.

```
declare module "*.vue" {
    import Vue from "vue";
    export default Vue;
}
```

It looks like this file is only read/applyed once and not after? Not sure.

Comment: Is this just with `hot` or is it also with `watch`?

Comment: The problem is also there with `watch`. It works on the first try, but as soon as I change any file, I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `ts-loader` doesn't support [HMR](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/hot-module-replacement) yet.

- https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#hot-module-replacement

I installed [fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/TypeStrong/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin) and updated `webpack.mix.js` to:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const path = require('path');

const ResolveTypeScriptPlugin = require("resolve-typescript-plugin").default;
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');

mix.webpackConfig({
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: "ts-loader",
                options: {
                    appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
                    transpileOnly: true
                },
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.vue'],
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname + '/resources'),
            '@store': path.resolve(__dirname + '/resources/js/store'),
            '@components': path.resolve(__dirname + '/resources/js/components')
        },
        fullySpecified: false,
        plugins: [new ResolveTypeScriptPlugin()]
    },
    plugins: [new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin()],
    devtool: 'source-map'
}).sourceMaps();

mix.ts('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.sass', 'public/css').sourceMaps()
    .vue();

mix.extract();
```

Now everything is working fine but I'm still not sure why `watch` was also affected and where exactly the problem was.

Comment: For me issue hasn't resolved even after configuring ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin
my problem is that in my .d.ts file I'm declaring global variable like this ```declare const DOTNET_API_ENDPOINT: string;``` typescript doesn't give any error on first run, however if I trigger hot refresh by changing something in my component, it would the show  TS2304: Cannot find name 'DOTNET_API_ENDPOINT'.
on update.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not using Typescript, but the same thing was happening to me, when i ran `npm run watch/hot` where only successful on the first change of the code, then, you can not see the changes until you run `npm run watch/hot` or `npm run dev` again. The strange thing was that everything was compiling successfully on every change I made.

I manage to debug it with git, and found out that I was importing a component with a wrong name but did not get an error on the console.
My component name was `WhosApplying.vue`

I got:

`import WhosApplying from "@/whosApplying.vue"`

And change it for:

`import WhosApplying from "@/WhosApplying.vue";`

That mistake in the `w` instead of `W` make me lose hours.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this using laravel-mix after adding typescript to an Inertia / Vue 3 project.

Using Volar (Not Vuter)

To fix it I changed my `webpack.config.js` file from:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve('resources/js'),
        },
    },
};
```

to:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: "ts-loader",
                options: {
                    appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
                    transpileOnly: true
                },
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.vue'],
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname + '/resources/js'),
        },
    },
};
```